# Options vs Preferences vs Settings? What do they mean, and for what should I use them?

Tags: terminology, gui, settings, labels, preferences

Across the various different programs, you will most often have a menu item called:

`Preferences`

- Firefox
- Chrome
- Gedit
- Synaptic (Under a `Settings` menu column)
- Hexchat (Under a `Settings` menu column)
- Gnome-Terminal
- Thunderbird
- Rhythmbox

---

Less often:

`Options`

- QtCreator

---

and less often:

`Settings`

- Gvim
- Chrome

---

Preferences seems to be the most used, but it is absent in some programs. Are the terms synonymous, or is there a distinction to be made as to where such labels are supposed to lead to?

Comment: Very closely related question over on User Experience: [Options, preferences, settings, configurations: What to call them in my application?](http://ux.stackexchange.com/q/17442/53062) Also related: [Which is the more common term used: Preferences or Settings?](http://ux.stackexchange.com/q/43040/53062) and [Where should the “preferences” item go in a desktop application?](http://ux.stackexchange.com/q/340/53062)

Comment: What ecosystem are you developing for? Mac OS, Windows, Gnome, KDE, iOS, Android all have a human interface guideline/style guide that discuss the naming of menus. But be aware that such names are subject to localization. Finding an *English* name for Prefs/Settings is only a small part of the problem.

Answer (score 3):

It's the lack of style guides. On Mac systems you have `Preferences` fixed to store your options and settings.  Other systems prefer whatever the programmer's taste is to name preferences.